# Can anyone explain this snippet of Javascript code?

Tags: javascript, regex

Reading this [discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/comp.lang.javascript/g0n_Tu8qro4), I didn't understand what this means:

```
 $1X$2
```

Simply **X**?

And about this other code:

```
 str = str.replace(/(<script.*?>)(.*)(?=<\/script>)/gi, function(x,y,z)
 {return y+z.replace(/a/gi,'Z')})
```

Here is what I didn't understand:

- `?=`
- how does `function(x,y,z)` works? i.e. from where it take `x`, `y` and `z`?

I'll be very grateful if someone could explain in a clear way this code.

Comment: There are some great answers here.  Just thought I would throw in an additional resource for javascript regex https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The $1 and $2 are referencing the captured sub-expressions (which are delimited by parentheses `()`) from the regular expression in the previous argument to `.replace()`.

The ?= is a positive lookahead. http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

The `function(x, y, z)` is an anonymous function expression that does a similar thing to referencing $1 and $2, but it stores them in variables instead.

Answer (score 4):

1. The string "$1X$2" used as the second argument to a `.replace()` call includes references to **groups** from the regular expression first argument. Groups — portions of the regular expression in parentheses — collect the characters they match for use later. The substrings "$1" and "$2" mean, "whatever was matched by the group 1" (or group 2).
2. When the second argument to a call to `.replace()` is a function, JavaScript passes the match information to the function as arguments. The first argument is always the entire match.  The subsequent arguments are the matched groups.

Thus:

```
alert("hello world".replace(/(ell)(o w)/, "$2$1");
// alerts "ho wellorld"
```

Answer (score 4):

This is all about capturing groups. `(` and `)` capture everything between, so you can later access substrings of your match.

`$1` refers to the first captured group, `$2` to the second one (so first and second pair of parentheses, respectively). (`$0` would refer to the whole match.)

The variant with the callback function does the same, but here the variables `x`, `y` and `z` are filled with the captured groups (corresponding to `$0`, `$1` and `$2` respectively).

Finally `?=` opens a lookahead. That asserts that this possition in the match is followed by `<\/script>` without actually advancing the regex engine in the matched string and also without including this part in the match.